# JAX-RS request taking custom object

Tags: java, jax-rs

In a specific JAX-RS based web service implementation there is a need of a custom object to be sent in the web service request.
I am aware of returning objects from a JAX-RS based web service but not quite sure of sending a object during the request.

Can some body help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance,
Arijit Bose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `MessageBodyReader` for your custom object such that:

```
public class YourClassReader implements MessageBodyReader<YourClass> {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable...

    @Override
    YourClass readFrom...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You annotate the method with `@POST` and `@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })` (or json, or whatever) and add a parameter. If you're using JAXB, the parameter can be a JAXB object and it will be unmarshalled for you automatically from the incoming XML.

Comment: +1 - In my experience XML is pretty ubiquitous here. Most JAX-RS implementations (eg Jersey, CXF) will automatically figure out simple beans described in XML - it just works. For more complicated beans you might have to add JAXB annotations.